Lie derivative of $X^\flat$
Let $X$ be a vector field and suppose we have a Riemannian metric $g$. This allows identification of tangent and cotangent spaces, and we may consider $X^\flat := g(X, \cdot)$ as a 1-form.
Does there exist an expression of $\mathcal{L}_Y X^\flat$ in terms of $g, X$?
My intuition expects an identity such as:
$$\mathcal{L}_Y X^\flat = \mathcal{L}_Y (g) (X , \cdot) + g(\mathcal{L}_Y X, \cdot) $$

Yes of course. Simply apply the $1$-form $\mathcal{L}_Y(X^{\flat})$ on an arbitrary vector field $Z$ and unwind definitions. This works for any derivation-like object $D_Y$ acting on all the tensors, so for example Lie-derivative and covariant derivative (though if you use a metric-compatible connection, then the first term drops out by hypothesis, and shows that covariant derivative commutes with the musical isomorphism).

If I unpack definitions as a derivative at $t_0 = 0$ of the pullback of the flow  $\varphi_t$ of $Y$, then I can shift this to a pushforward onto some other vector, say $Z$. Then I can undo the flat and differentiate to obtain $g(X, -\mathcal{L}_Y Z) $. This doesn't seem like the guessed identity.

don’t work with flows directly I just mean $\mathcal{L}_Y(X^{\flat})=\mathcal{L}_Y[X^{\flat}(Z)]- X^{\flat}[\mathcal{L}_YZ]$. This is just the Leibniz rule for 1-forms and Lie derivatives (you can either take this as a postulate or prove this much more very generally using flows). Now proceed, and just use the known Leibniz rules.

I agree with your calculation, but I also believe the result in my previous comment, which only used a very basic property (def of $\mathcal{L}$ and that pushforward is the dual of pullback). Which does not look like it agrees with your comment. Furthermore, neither of these calculations seem to immediately obviously agree with the proposed identity in the question. I would like to be sure there is not a gap in my understanding.

If you think there’s a discrepancy, then the issue is with your treatment of pulling back along the flow (which I don’t really feel like delving into… because it really is a pain to work with directly).

Also, keep in mind that as mentioned in the first comment, this result is not specific to the Lie derivative (another reason I want to stay away from flows in this situation), and only uses the derivation-nature of it. So, with this in mind, do you know how to continue from my equality to get the desired result?

I believe the calculation in my comment is consistent with the identity in my question, and thus is consistent with yours. The pushforward of $\varphi$ that is acting on $Z$ can be "pulled through" the metric as $\varphi^_t g ( \varphi^_t X, Z)$, which can then be differentiated with the product rule to obtain the expected Lie derivative of $g$ and Lie derivative of $X$.

For any $Y \in \Gamma(TM)$.
\begin{align*}
\mathcal L_Y (X^\flat)
&= \mathcal L_Y (g(X, \,\cdot\,)) \\
&= (\mathcal L_Y g)(X, \,\cdot\,) + g(\mathcal L_Y X, \,\cdot\,) \\
&= (\mathcal L_Y g)(X, \,\cdot\,) + (\mathcal L_Y X)^\flat ,
\end{align*}
which coincides with your guess. If you like, you can regard the quantity $\mathcal L_Y g$ in the last expression as the Lie derivative of the musical isomorphism $\,\cdot\,^\flat: TM \to T^*M$ itself.
The first and third equalities use the definition of $\,\cdot\,^\flat$, and the second equality uses the Leibniz Rule for the Lie derivative (and the compatibility of the Lie derivative with tensor contractions).
